# How to change ReSharper header text comment style

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I'm using Resharper's "File Header Text" option to add a licensing comment in my files. 
However, the comments are made using double forward-slash and in my codebase the licensing comments are done using the `/*` comment style.

Is there any way to change this?

Comment: please review this : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/File_Header_Style.html It might help you.

Comment: If there is such an option I can't find it. You may be better advised to ask Jetbrains, as if the answer is 'no' they can turn it into a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

A late reply, but this is not currently possible. There's a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-468109/File-header-should-have-an-option-for-comment-style-line-block-no-commenting) which could use some upvotes.